# datagridview paging system error: Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '__Page' to data type int

Tags: asp.net, sql, gridview, paging

I create a dataTable and its rows:

```
public void method(string ID)
{
      sqlConn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["U"]);
        sqlComm = new SqlCommand();
        sqlComm.Connection = sqlConn;

        DataTable Tablo = new DataTable();

        Tablo.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("F1", typeof(string)));
        Tablo.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("F2", typeof(string)));

        DataRow row;

        try
        {
            sqlComm.CommandText = "Some query...";
            sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Iden", ID);
            sqlConn.Open();           
            SqlDataReader sqlRead;
            sqlRead = sqlComm.ExecuteReader();
            while (sqlRead.Read())
            {
                rowNumber++;
                string aim = sqlRead["Aim"].ToString();
                row = Tablo.NewRow();
                row["F1"] = sqlRead["_ID"].ToString();
                row["F2"] = sqlRead["KK_No"].ToString();

                Tablo.Rows.Add(row);
            }
            sqlRead.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {

            sqlConn.Close();
        }

        gv.DataSource = Tablo;
        gv.DataBind();

}
```

and this is gridview aspx side:

```
 <asp:GridView ID="gv" runat="server" Width="100%" 
                                        AutoGenerateColumns="False" CssClass="listebaslik" 
                                        EnableModelValidation="True" AllowPaging="True" 
                                        onpageindexchanging="gv_PageIndexChanging" PageSize="15">
                                        <Columns>
                                            <asp:BoundField DataField="F1" HeaderText="1_No">
                                            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#006699" ForeColor="White" />
                                            <ItemStyle ForeColor="Navy" />
                                            </asp:BoundField>
                                            <asp:BoundField DataField="F2" HeaderText=" 2_No">
                                            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#006699" ForeColor="White" />
                                            <ItemStyle ForeColor="Navy" />
                                            </asp:BoundField>

                                        </Columns>
                                        <PagerStyle ForeColor="#3333CC" />
                                    </asp:GridView>
```

and finally its paging part:

```
protected void gv_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        gvS.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        method(ID);
    }
```

It works normally but when the click page two i have this error in the catch: `Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '__Page' to data type int`

How to fix it?Thanks fot your answers

Answer (score 1):

maybe `ID` have different value in

```
method(ID);

public void method(string ID)
```